# Few questions about Lord Venkateshwara temple

Tags: vishnu, name, lakshmi, venkateshwara

Priests in venkateshwara temples chant in Tamil like 'palland palland...' In other temples, slokas chanted might chant in sanskrit. Priests allotted in venkateswara temples are mostly tamilians. And, also they close the garbhagriha of the lord and open only in certain intervals whereas they keep open the doors of his wives.
And, also help me with the names of his wives. I get confused with (who is who) their numerous names like padmavati, goda devi, bhudevi, and manga, lakshmi etc.

So here are my questions:

1. Why do priests in lord venkateshwara temple chant mantras, slokas only in Tamil?
2. Why they close the garbhagriha of the lord and open only in certain intervals whereas they keep open the doors of his wives?
3. What are the other names of venkateshwara wives?

Comment: Currently your question has multiple questions. Please break them in multiple question post.

Comment: The Tamil chanting is Shri Divya prabandham. It’s like how in North Indian temples the Aarti is done in local language, though prabandham is on a different level.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto So, should I split the question into 2 or 3?

Comment: @Archit Not just in tamilnadu, in other states too they do the same.

Comment: @Learner Q1. Why do priests in lord venkateshwara temple chant mantras, slokas only in Tamil? Q2. Why they close the garbhagriha of the lord and open only in certain intervals whereas they keep open the doors of his wives Q3. names of venkateshwara wives.